# Sharepoint List within a Main Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to have multiple lists within a main list.

```
Like: List A (Main)
------List 1
------List 2
------List 3
```

Since I would like to have different user permissions for all of the lists within the main list.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work that way. The closest you can get is enabling folders on your list and assigning unique permissions to each folder.

Comment: Also look into SharePoint Folders+Metadata inheritance option called: DocumentSets

Comment: true, if it is document based, then absolutely document sets